# Аналитическая геометрия: найти точки касания эллипсоида и конуса

Tags: математика

Пусть даны точка `P(xp,yp,zp)` и эллипсоид, у которого известны полуоси и центр, его уравнение: `x^2/a^2+y^2/a^2+z^2/b^2=1`.

Точка P лежит за пределами эллипсоида в некотором отдалении. Множество касательных к эллипсоиду, проведенных из `P`, образует коническую поверхность. Надо найти общий вид точек касания этого конуса и эллипсоида (понятно, что эти точки будут принадлежать эллипсу, то есть задача по сути сводится к отысканию уравнения эллипса касания конуса и эллипсоида).

Можно ли здесь упростить задачу, перейдя к сферическим координатам? Если да, то как действовать дальше? Если нет, то вопрос аналогичный.

Comment: Свойство "быть касательной" не изменяется при сжатии-растяжении осей. Поэтому вы можете перейти в систему координат, в которой эллипс - сфера, найти уравнение касательной к этой сфере, и растянуть координаты обратно.

Comment: Хорошо, но вот как быть дальше? Понятно, что задача упростится, но я пока даже не имею понятия, как двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Явное выражение для точек, в которых конус лучей из точки `P = (x,y,z)` касается эллипсоида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точки заданы в параметрическом виде. Если установить `omega = 2pi`, а `t` пробегает от 0 до 1, то это выражение пробежит по всем искомым точкам.

Для вывода этого выражения я использовал систему символьной математики `sympy`. Пошаговый вывод [опубликовал как блокнот Jupyter](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/math/1293488/Untitled7.ipynb).

Идея очень простая. Нужно перейти в систему координат, в которой эллипс трансформирован в единичную сферу, а точка `P` находится на оси `Z`
. В этом случае уравнение точек, в которых сфера касается конуса, выводится легко и непринуждённо. Остаётся только преобразовать координаты обратно. Для этого я воспользовался `sympy`, чтобы не ковыряться с бесконечными цепочками буковок.

**UPDATE**

Я добавил в [блокнот Jupyter](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/math/1293488/Untitled7.ipynb) численный метод вычисления касательного эллипса.

Идея в том, чтобы в системе координат `C` найти три вектора - центр касательной окружности и два ортогональных вектора, вращение которых описывает искомую окружность.

Эти векторы в системе координат `A` формируют касательный эллипс.

Функция вычисления трёх векторов на языке Python (не силёт в Матлабе).

````
def tangent_cone(a,b, P):
    """
    Возвращает три вектора `c,v1,v2`, определяющие эллипс, по точкам которого эллипсоид касается конус с вершиной `P`.
    
    Точки r_tan эллипса вычисляются так:
    ```
    c, v1, v2 = tangent_cone(a,b, P)
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    r_tan = c.reshape(3,1) + v1.reshape(3,1)*np.cos(t) + v2.reshape(3,1)*np.sin(t)
    ```
    В этом случае r_tan - матрица из 3 строк и 100 столбцов. Первая строка - координата `x` точек, 
    вторая строка - координата `y`, третья строка - координата `z`.
    """
    assert P.ndim == 1
    assert len(P) == 3
    
    x,y,z = P
    R = np.sqrt(x**2/a**2 + y**2/a**2 + z**2/b**2)
    cos_theta = (z/b)/R
    # theta меняется от 0 до pi, поэтому sin(theta) >= 0
    sin_theta = np.sqrt(1 - cos_theta**2)
    
    sin_phi = (y/a)/(sin_theta*R)
    cos_phi = (x/a)/(sin_theta*R)
    
    center = np.array([a*cos_phi*sin_theta/R, a*sin_phi*sin_theta/R, b*cos_theta/R])
    
    r = np.sqrt(1 - 1/R**2)
    v1 = np.array([a*r*cos_phi*cos_theta, a*r*sin_phi*cos_theta, -b*r*sin_theta])
    v2 = np.array([-a*r*sin_phi, a*r*cos_phi, 0])
    
    return center, v1, v2
````

Для вычисления точек эллипса нужно вращать вектор вокруг точки `center`:

```
c, v1, v2 = tangent_cone(a,b, P)
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r_tan = c.reshape(3,1)+v1.reshape(3,1)*np.cos(t) + v2.reshape(3,1)*np.sin(t)
```

В матрице `r_tan` три строки по 100 координат. Строки соответствуют координатам `x`, `y` и `z`.

Пример касательных к эллипсоиду с полуосями 1 и 4 из точки с координатами `(5,5,5)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за такую работу! Но у меня есть вопрос. Я эту задачу делаю в Matlab, и хотела бы нарисовать весь этот результат для наглядности. Я пока не понимаю, как мне прилепить тут изменение t от 0 до 1, потому что из-за того, что x, y, z - массивы точек, выходит не одна матрица перехода из B в C (и из C в B), а по количеству точек в массиве. Свой код пришлю как ответ на вопрос. Но с ним нужно что-то сделать (конкретно с t).

Comment: @Fire13nyu я добавил в решение пример вычисления эллипса.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку эллипсоид - центрированная вокруг начала координат таблетка c короткой осью по OZ, т.е. довольно простой, можно попробовать и прямые методы.

Если касательная проведена из точки `(px, py, pz)` к точке `(tx, ty, tz)` эллипсоида, то нормаль к эллипсоиду в это точке перпендикулярна касательной, скалярное произведение равно нулю. А нормаль к поверхности эллипсоида в этой точке, согласно справочника Корнов, выглядит как `(tx/a^2, ty/a^2, tz/b^2)` (тут я мог немного ошибиться с коэффициентами)

```
(px-tx)*tx/a^2 + (py-ty)*ty/a^2 + (pz-tz)*tz/b^2 = 0
px*tx/a^2 + py*ty/a^2 + pz*tz/b^2 = tx^2/a^2 + ty^2/a^2 + tz^2/b^2
```

Но правая часть равна единице (согласно исходному уравнению), поэтому получаем уравнение плоскости, секущей эллипсоид

```
px*x/a^2 + py*y/a^2 + pz*z/b^2 - 1 = 0
```

Для нахождения центра сечения выражаем z, подставляем в исходное уравнение, получаем эллипс в OXY, являющийся проекцией эллипса сечения. Для него центр найти нетрудно, потом переходим обратно в трехмерное пространство.

Остаётся найти оси эллипса (не дописано)

Answer (score 0):

```
function [] = myfunc(a,b,xc,yc,zc)
x=-20:0.1:20;
y=x; z=x;
% A - initial coordinate system; B - coordinate system, where ellipsoid is the unit sphere;
% C - coordinate system, where ellipsoid is the unit sphere and Oc is on axis Z
A2B = [1/a,0,0;0,1/a,0;0,0,1/b]; 
B2A = [a,0,0;0,a,0;0,0,b];

% translate the coordinates of the camera into a coordinate system B
OC = A2B*[xc,yc,zc]';
XC = OC(1); YC = OC(2); ZC = OC(3);

R=sqrt(x.^2/a^2+y.^2/a^2+z.^2/b^2);
theta = acos(ZC./R);
phi = acos(XC./(R.*sin(theta)));
B2C = cell(length(R));
C2B = cell(length(R));
OP = cell(length(R));
omega = 2*pi;
t = 0:0.01:1;
for k=1:length(R)
    B2C{k} = [cos(phi(k)).*cos(theta(k)),sin(phi(k)).*cos(theta(k)),-sin(theta(k));...
           -sin(theta(k)),            cos(phi(k)),                0            ;...
           sin(theta(k)).*cos(phi(k)),sin(phi(k)).*sin(theta(k)), cos(theta(k))];
       
    C2B{k} = [cos(phi(k)).*cos(theta(k)),-sin(phi(k)),sin(theta(k)).*cos(phi(k));...
           sin(phi(k)).*cos(theta(k)), cos(phi(k)),sin(phi(k)).*sin(theta(k));... 
           -sin(theta(k)),             0,          cos(theta(k))            ];
       
       
    r = sqrt(1-1/(R(k)^2));
    h = 1/R(k);
    OP{k} = B2A*C2B{k}*[r*cos(omega*t),r*sin(omega*t),h]';
end

end
```